# SQLite trigger error : rollback

Tags: sql, sqlite

I get the following error when I try to create this trigger in SQLite

```
create trigger timeslot_check1 after insert on section

for each row
when(new.time_slot_id not in(select time_slot_id
                            from time_slot))
begin
    rollback
end;
```

ERROR : near "rollback": syntax error:

Comment: Shouldn't this have a BEGIN TRANSACTION ?
Or are you missing a semicolon after ROLLBACK ?

Comment: @RamMehta none of these worked

Answer (score 4):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), the only SQL commands allowed in a trigger body are UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, and SELECT.

To raise an error, you must use the [RAISE() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#raise) from inside a query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER timeslot_check1
BEFORE INSERT ON section
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.time_slot_id NOT IN (SELECT time_slot_id FROM time_slot)
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "invalid timeslot");
END;
```

Anyway, this check can be done much easier with a [foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Comment: your code gives the ERROR : near "RAISE": syntax error: